# How can I set variables with JQuery in my HTML Markup

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, variables

am working on the Accordion- Function of Bootstrap, which should be to see only on Smartphones. Now I want to automize my code.

Here my HTML Markup:

```
<div id="accordion" class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">    
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
                <h3 class="h3_toggle1">Titel 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1">
                <div class="card-body">Content 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
                <h3 class="h3_toggle2">Titel 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2">
                <div class="card-body">Content 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JS Code:

```
  function collapse(n) {
    $(".h3_toggle" + n)
      .attr("data-toggle", "collapse")
      .attr("data-target", "#collapse" + n)
      .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
      .attr("aria-controls", "collapse" + n);
    $("#collapse" + n)
      .addClass("collapse")
      .attr("aria-labelledby", "#heading" + n)
      .attr("data-parent", "#accordion");
   }
   function expand(n) {
     $(".h3_toggle" + n)
       .removeAttr("data-toggle")
       .removeAttr("data-target")
       .removeAttr("aria-expanded")
       .removeAttr("aria-controls");
     $("#collapse" + n)
       .removeClass("collapse")
       .removeAttr("aria-labelledby")
       .removeAttr("data-parent");
   }


   $(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    collapse(1);
    collapse(2);
  } else {
    expand(1);
    expand(2);
  }
});
```

This works well. But with every adding a new card I have to add the number of the card, but I wanne write instead of h3_toggle1 or heading1 and collapse1 ... in h3_toggle and heading and collapse.

So I wanna change JUST my HTML Markup, The JS Code is fine, just wanna change this part:

```
   $(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    collapse(1);
    collapse(2);
  } else {
    expand(1);
    expand(2);
  }  
});
```

in:

```
   $(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    collapse(i);
  } else {
    expand(i);
  }
});
```

How can I do this?

I tried this solution:

```
   $(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) collapse(i);
   $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i)); 
  } else {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) expand(i);
   $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i)); 
  }
});
```

But I dont know why it doesnt work.

Comment: get a count of cards before calling resize function and then pass it to resize rather hardcoding the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var i = 0;
$(".h3-toggle").each(function () {
  i++;
  $(this).addClass("h3-toggle" + (i));
  $(this).parent().attr("id", "heading" + (i));
  $(this).parent().next().attr("id", "collapse" + (i));
  //alert(1);
  //alert($(window).width());
  if ($(window).width() <= 575) {
    collapse(i);
  } else {
    expand(i);
  }
});

});


$(window).resize(function () {
var i = 0;
$(".h3-toggle").each(function () {
  i++;
  if ($(window).width() <= 575) {
    collapse(i);
  } else {
    expand(i);

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
   for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    collapse(i);
    $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i));
   }

  } else {
   for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++)  {
    expand(i);
    $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i));
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer! It is interesting because it doesnt matter on which header (h3_toggle1 oder h3_toggle2) I am clicking, it just the second card expand. Do you know why?

Comment: just stop using var in for loops, like you did: for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)...

in such case 'i' got higher area of visibility, using your code as example we got:

$(window).resize(function() {
var i
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) collapse(i);
   $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i)); 
  } else {
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) expand(i);
   $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i)); 
  }
});

second: you didn't use quotes, (   $(".h3_toggle").addClass("h3_toggle"+(i));  out of for loop)   - in such case you got last 'i', wich is 2

Comment: https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/ - here is var-let in for-loops difference description

Comment: I understand. So I used your code but it still doesnt work.